# Want an accordion-like structure except shows all by default- Recommendations?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

As the title suggests, I'm looking for a nice set of horizontal buttons or tabs that shows all the children divs by default and the rest of the buttons/tabs close everything except the one you clicked.  The show-all would be expected as the first button/tab.  I could always write my own code to do this but there's the whole why reinvent the wheel thing...

Suggestions?

EDIT:  so here is what I came up with based on the suggestions:

Jquery:

```
$( "#tabs ul li a" ).click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('href');
    $(id).show().siblings().not('ul').hide();
});
```

html:

```
<div  id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab1">tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3">tab 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab4">tab 4</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab1">info 1</div>
    <div id="tab2">info 2</div>
    <div id="tab3">info 3</div>
    <div id="tab4">info 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks good Brandon, nice work.  One suggestion to consider is removing the `<a>` tags in this case, since they don't actually link anywhere, and using a [data-*](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) attribute to pass the div id.  [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/zcMfV/1/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're asking, but outside of [jQuery UI accordian](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) functionality, hiding and showing sibling elements is pretty straightforward by chaining calls:

```
$('div#id').click(function(){
   $(this).show().siblings().hide();
});
```

Obviously this is a pretty basic example that doesn't deal with child elements, but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: would you not be better to have along the lines of `$('#accordion .section').click...`

Comment: @Hailwood: Yeah, that probably makes more sense, but I usually keep my answers generic if the question doesn't give me many details to work with.

Comment: Both of you guys have comments that helped me.  I'll edit my post to show what I came up with based on your suggestions.  Please! let me know what you think of my code.